# What is InternalNode in chrome heap profile

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am diagnosing a memory leak in a jQuery based single page application using the Chrome DevTools heap snapshot tool as described on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/#discover_detached_dom_tree_memory_leaks_with_heap_snapshots

I have solved some issues this way, but I have now hit a roadblock where I can no longer determine what is keeping an object in memory. For example, for one of the objects it returns the following retainers:
[image: heap snapshot]

From what I can tell, the object is retained because it's used inside a closure scope of a click event.
But the click event is on a detached HtmlDivElement, which should be garbage collected.
It is somehow linked to the window object via InternalNode objects. I have searched all over the internet, but I'm unable to find what these InternalNode objects are.

My question is, what are these InternalNode objects and how I can "free" them so my objects are garbage collected.

Comment: See [this comment](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/include/cppgc/name-provider.h;l=12) in the source code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I see there is a preprocessor symbol to turn off the "InternalNode" name hiding. I'll try if I can built chromium with that flag and check the heap profile again.

Comment: @wOxxOm I revealed the names of the InternalNode entries. The detached element is being kept alive by blink::MouseEventManager. I'll have to dive deeper, but it might be a chromium bug..

Comment: Probably https://crbug.com/1177010

Comment: @wOxxOm Damn. You're right! Clicking on an element outside the element being detached prevents the object leak.
Could you post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: You did all the work so it'd make sense if you post an answer. And move the update section from the question into the answer too.

Comment: Sure. Couldn't have done it without you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Leak is caused by https://crbug.com/1177010
Clicking on an element outside the detached element prevents the memory leak from occuring.

---

Following [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s comment, I have compiled a version of Chromium with the `enable_additional_blink_object_names` flag enabled so that it shows the names of the `InternalNode` objects.
It appears `blink:MouseEventManager` is preventing the detached dom element from being garbage collected.

[image]

This finally lead me to https://crbug.com/1177010, which I could confirm by clicking outside the detached element before taking another heap snapshot.

Comment: you two are genius! Those InternalNode confused me for a long time. But I wonder how can you find out that there is a blink's flag call "enable_additional_blink_object_names"?  I google it but I can not find anything useful.

Comment: @fun I cloned the chromium source code and searched for the string "InternalNode". It required a bit of knowledge of C.

Comment: The `enable_additional_blink_object_names` gn arg / flag was recently renamed to `cppgc_enable_object_names `. See: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0f5665fff2e1bf4f9b34e039e4db15d39be941f1

Answer (score 4):

There have been some changes in this space in the last couple of years. As of November 2023, these steps will get you useful names instead of "InternalNode".

1. Download [Chrome for Testing](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/), or build your own Chromium with the GN build flag `cppgc_enable_object_names = true`.
2. In the developer tools, in Settings, under Experiments, check the box entitled "Show option to expose internals in heap snapshots".
3. In the developer tools, in the Memory tab, check the box entitled "Expose internals (includes additional implementation-specific details)".
4. Take a heap snapshot.