# Compile chromium cannot revealed the names of the InternalNode entries

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium

I want to reveal the names of the InternalNode entries but fail. Similar to the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802111/what-is-internalnode-in-chrome-heap-profile).

I pulled the latest chromium code, run the command

```
gn gen out/Default
```

Updated the file `out/Default/args.gn`

```
# Set build arguments here. See `gn help buildargs`.
is_debug = true
is_component_build = true
symbol_level = 2
cppgc_enable_object_names = true
```

run the command

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

However, the generated chrome is not as expected to reveal the names of the `InternalNode` entries.

Comment: If you look at the linked post, you have not specified `enable_additional_blink_object_names` in your args.gn file

Comment: It says the `enable_additional_blink_object_names` gn arg / flag was recently renamed to `cppgc_enable_object_names` see [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0f5665fff2e1bf4f9b34e039e4db15d39be941f1) @Asesh

Comment: Why don't you ask this question here instead: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev It's Chromium developers official Google group

Answer (score 0):

There's a few more steps to this than you did but what you already did is correct. Let me break it down:

**Step 1:**

Compile Chromium with the `cppgc_enable_object_names` flag in the `args.gn` file by following the instructions on the official build pages for your platform: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/get_the_code.md

**Step 2:**

In DevTool experiments, enable "Show option to expose internals in heap snapshots"

[image: Devtools Experiments]

**Step 3:**

In the Memory Profiler, tick the box saying "Expose Internals"

[image: Memory Profiler]

**Step 4:**

Record your profile and you will now have internal nodes appear as well.

[image: Retainers with internal objects]